# How can I apply generics in Java having nested bound type parameters?

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance, nested-generics

I have few classes:

```
class A [ Base class ]
    class B1
         class B11
         class B12
    class B2
         class B21
         class B22
```

I want to use generics like this

```
A<B1<B11>>> a1 = new A<>();
A<B1<B12>>> a2 = new A<>();
A<B2<B21>>> a3 = new A<>();
A<B2<B22>>> a4 = new A<>();
```

So my class A is something like this

```
Class A<T> {
private T t;
Getter and Setters...
}
```

Above class A can take T as `B1<B11>` or `B1<B12>` or  `B2<B21>` or `B2<B22>` type.

```
Class B1<T> {
private T t;
Getter and Setters...
}
```

```
Class B2<T> {
private T t;
Getter and Setters...
}
```

Above Class B1 will take T as B11 or B12 type and Class B2 will take T as B21 or B22 type.

**Note**: Cannot use only B1 or B2 because of code readebility.

**Question 1**. Is it possible in Java using generics? If yes, then how can I achieve this.
**Question 2**. Can we apply inheritance for above case and also applying generics with that? If yes, then how can I achieve this.

Thank you. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "Is it possible in Java using generics?" The code you showed is doing exactly that. "Can we apply inheritance?" *How* do you want to apply inheritance?

Comment: @Sweeper I think it's not possible practically but I was thinking if we can do something like class B<T> extends A<U>{ private U<T> t; }. I am not sure.

Comment: What is the indentation at the beginning supposed to express? Apparently not subclass relationships, as the code examples beneath it do not have `extends` clauses. If there was a subclass relationship, there would be no need to repeat the declaration of `t` in every class. But since `T` has no constraints, there is no relationship to any of those `B…` classes. It can be `B1<B11>` etc., but it can also be `List<List<List<List<Map<String,Integer>>>>>` or whatever.

Comment: @Holger The indentation represents the heirarchy. I thought of using inheritance and extends clause as well but I am not sure how I can pass the bounded type parameters in child classes.

Comment: Like `class B1<T> extends A<T> { … }`?

Comment: @Holger But the B1<T> where T can be B11 or B12. And for A<T> T can be B1<B11> or B2<B21>. In short both T are not same type. And the method you suggested is not working.

Comment: I’m not sure whether you understood what *inheritance* actually means.